# lodash error `_.intersection is not a function`

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to use `_.intersection` and `_.difference`. The problem is that I'm getting errors saying they are not defined. Some of the other methods such as `_.forEach` are working. Could there be some conflict on the `_` object? How would I determine how to fix this?

here's some sample code and a screenshot with intersection not showing up:

```
function checkIsDirty(){
    console.log("here is version:");
    console.log(_.VERSION);  // works fine outputs "4.17.10"
    console.log(_.intersection([2, 1], [2, 3]));
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using the full build or the core build?

Comment: ahh... @sbrass core ... that's probably it.

Comment: Are you sure that you have lodash loaded, and not underscore? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41370337/detecting-if-is-lodash-or-underscore/41382226

Comment: @cale_b They both have `_.intersection`. And 4.17.10 is not an underscore.js version.

Comment: yeah, it looks fixed by using full version rather than core. thx @sbrass